# Don't get AdMob running on emulator (android 2.2)

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

I'm just trying to get admob running and tested different "working" code examples from here.
None of them works.

In the activity I have:

oncreate()

```
    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
    r.addTestDevice("X3XFX518X7DE1FD879XA5XXAX1AX8BXX"); //no clue why this string
    ad.loadAd(r);
```

In the view definition I have inserted the following (and yes instead of myPubID there is actually my real PUB ID):

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/ad" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    ads:adUnitId="<myPubID>" 
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

All I get is a black screen for 1 second.

Following log (logcat) is printed during execution

```
08-09 10:45:03.527: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc de.syrtec.android.bogloid for activity de.syrtec.android.bogloid/.StartSeite: pid=4402 uid=10043 gids={3003}
08-09 10:45:04.887: ERROR/Ads(4402): Could not get currentAdManager.
08-09 10:45:05.397: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@450d4998
08-09 10:45:05.567: INFO/Ads(4402): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
08-09 10:45:06.159: INFO/Ads(4402): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1.5,"slotname":"********;</script></head><body></body></html>
08-09 10:45:07.528: WARN/webcore(4402): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
08-09 10:45:07.848: INFO/Ads(4402): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=0&u_sd=1.5&slotname=*****: "null">
08-09 10:45:08.809: DEBUG/webviewglue(4402): nativeDestroy view: 0x2bbb30
08-09 10:45:08.818: INFO/Ads(4402): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
08-09 10:45:11.168: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3148): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32 objects / 1640 bytes in 131ms
08-09 10:45:16.237: DEBUG/dalvikvm(272): GC_EXPLICIT freed 195 objects / 12168 bytes in 137ms
```

I use GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar and Android 2.2 on Emulator.

In my admob account there is no filter and adsense is activated.

I also tried it by instanciating the AdView and adding it to the rootlayout with:
(referring to http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "PUB_ID");
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and got the same behaviour with the following log:

```
08-09 10:49:18.367: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc de.syrtec.android.bogloid for activity de.syrtec.android.bogloid/.StartSeite: pid=4543 uid=10043 gids={3003}
08-09 10:49:19.297: ERROR/Ads(4543): Could not get currentAdManager.
08-09 10:49:19.797: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44fe4350 de.syrtec.android.bogloid/.StartSeite}
08-09 10:49:20.067: INFO/Ads(4543): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
08-09 10:49:20.379: INFO/Ads(4543): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script*****;</script></head><body></body></html>
08-09 10:49:20.397: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@450d20b8
08-09 10:49:22.737: WARN/webcore(4543): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
08-09 10:49:22.957: INFO/Ads(4543): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=0&u_sd=1.5&slotname=***** "null">
08-09 10:49:24.038: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4543): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3826 objects / 234984 bytes in 154ms
08-09 10:49:24.058: DEBUG/webviewglue(4543): nativeDestroy view: 0x2c5320
08-09 10:49:24.058: INFO/Ads(4543): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
08-09 10:49:24.078: DEBUG/webviewglue(4543): nativeDestroy view: 0x2b81d0
```

Has anyone a clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried like in the suggested tutorial ([blog.kerul.net/2011/05/](http://blog.kerul.net/2011/05/installing-google-admob-into-android.html))

but I only get a black view for a second and then return to android "desktop":

The source looks now like this:

activity class:

```
class StartActivity extends AdActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    re.setTesting(true);
    adview.loadAd(re);
}
...
}
```

the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_PUB_ID" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And YES I replaced MY_PUB_ID with my real publisher id

Is there anything missing?
What Emulator do you use with which Android runtime?

Comment: Hmm... very interesting. Is this your all project, or there are more code? Firstly delete your re.addTestDevice(Adrequest.TEST_EMULATOR); if you use the re.setTesting(true) row, is doesn't needed. Did you try to made another project in Eclipse too, or is this the first? Probably, the problem, is not with the code, rather with the Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you :-) ..now the test-ad is displayed printing "Success! Now you are ready to travel through the App Galaxy"

So how to proceed with real ads? 

I would do like this :

1. remove the re.setTesting(true)
2. publish my app on app market
3. link app in admob to the actual real market url of the app

Is there still something missing or incorrect?

Comment: Finally :D What was the problem? Did you only deleted the re.addTestDevice?  Yes first you need to delete the re.setTesting(true) row from your project, then publish it. I think that you don't need the actual real market url, you only need to write your package name to the example what was showed on the admob's site. I'm happy that I could help you ;)

Comment: yes I only removed 
re.addTestDevice(Adrequest.TEST_EMULATOR); 
and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to place to the //no clue why this string your test device's code. I prefer to use setTesting(true) while test it, but you know. The problem can be this.

Oh and I see that your program can't receive ad because of the fault of the ad inventory
Place this in your layout at the com.google.ads.adView section: 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

And not forget to take an Internet permission to your manifest.

Hope it helps.

Edit: I'm not sure that this is your problem, but I think it can helps.

Comment: I prefer to set test device with r.addTestdevice(phoneID) too, then my dev phone receives test-ads, and I don't need to revert setTesting() to False when I release. Also if you use several dev phones and simulators, you just ad their ids, and it's done. As to the "//No clue...", there is no problem with this line :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I tried it like you suggested..and got the same behaviour and the second log output of my initial post

Comment: Probably it will helps:
http://blog.kerul.net/2011/05/installing-google-admob-into-android.html

At least I hope :)

Comment: looks very good....dummy compliant...so it should fit good to me ;)...gonna try it when I find the time

Comment: Hope it will helps, please write back if you could make something with it :)

Comment: just tried the tutorial..and after doing everything like a noob (what i am) there I read "it does not work on the emulator"...very nice...so I need to buy an android phone to test the ads...that's really amazingly smart..so admob was another waste of time..

Comment: It's working on emulator. I don't know what's your problem. Did you imported the re.setTesting(true); too?

Comment: yes :) ..I did post the activity and view source as an answer (can't post as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Lack of inventory means AdMob doesn't have any ads to serve, this is usual if your account is new, after a while your fill-rate will increase and more ads will be served.
If you see a green status light in your AdMob sites/app page, you shouldn't worry
Try adding adsense to increase your fill-rate [Enabling Google AdSense Ads in Your Applications](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/enabling-google-adsense-ads-your-applications).

edit: missed you already had adsense enabled

Comment: I got a green status with the notice: 
active: your Website is currently sending view requests to AdMob. (I dont understand why my site is talking to admob...)


Can I do anything to increase the fill-rate..To get a single ad displayed?...What for is actually the connection to my website as it has nothing to do with my app?

Comment: your site is a generic term admob uses for your publications, apps mobile websites etc... so it means your app is communicating with admob

Comment: so my the url of my site is used only as an identifier for my app right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're refering to here... if you look in the settings for your admob site it should be of type "android app" and the site url should be the url of your app on the android market market://details?id=com.your.app

Comment: I just wanted to get sdk to test admob...so I was forced to put an url there to download it...I won't put my app on the market when I don't know how it looks or whether it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have this experience of having the apps crashing and displaying messages such as this - "Error inflating class com.admob.ads.AdView" . Doing some research and testing I concluded the following XML attribute to display the AdView;

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="738a44d913034b9f"
        />  
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >







    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnkamus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Kesan" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncadang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cadang" />

</TableRow>


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

Complete tutorial is here - http://blog.kerul.net/2012/08/example-how-to-install-google-admob-6x.html